# How to calculate probability of a state given the partition function

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Given a canonical partition function $Z$, by the thermodynamic connection equations, I can say that $$A = -k_B T \ln Z$$
So, internal energy $U$ is given by
$$\langle E \rangle =U = -\frac{\partial \ ln Z}{\partial \beta}$$

My question is, how would I calculate the probability of the energy being equal to the average energy $U$, given by the above equation? How would I calculate the probability of the energy of the system being $kU$, where $k$ is some positive constant?

My question is, would the probability of the energy being
$$P(E=U) = e^{-\beta U}/Z$$
and
$$P(E=kU) = e^{-\beta kU}/Z?$$

How would you do this for an ideal gas partition function
$$Z = \frac{1}{N!} \left( \frac{2\pi m k_B T}{h^2}  \right)^{3N/2} V^N?$$

Comment: In general the probability of some event $A$ (in your case, $A$ is the set of all microstates with energy equal to $U$, but there is no reason to restrict to this case) is $P(A) = \sum_{\omega\in A} \exp(-H(\omega))/Z$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system. Of course, depending on your particular setting, replace the sum by an integral over $A$.

Comment: Thanks, @YvanVelenik. However, if I am dealing with an ideal gas, whose partition function I know, how would I calculate P(U)? Is there a way to neatly enumerate/integrate over all $\omega \in A$ as you have written there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the partition function, then it's straightforward to get the relevant distribution expressed in phase space coordinates $\Gamma$:

$$p(\Gamma) = \frac{e^{-\beta E(\Gamma)}}{Z}$$

But that's not the question! The question is about finding the distribution of the energies themselves. For this you need to project the above $6N$-dimensional probability distribution onto a single dimension:

$$p(E)=\int \delta(E-E(\Gamma))\frac{e^{-\beta E(\Gamma)}}{Z}d\Gamma$$

Which is a complicated $6N$-dimensional integral! So in general you will see that this question is extremely difficult and only soluble numerically (and usually not even to satisfactory precision). However, the ideal gas presents one of the few soluble cases, where you know that each velocity coordinate is a normal independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) variable. The sum of the squares of $3N$ random i.i.d. standard normal variables is known as the chi-square distribution:

$$\chi^2_{3N}(x)=\frac{x^{\frac{3N}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{2^{\frac{3N}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{3N}{2})}$$

And this gives you the probability density of observing a particular sum of squares of "dimensionless" velocities. For velocities with variance $\frac{1}{\beta m}$ (Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution) this is equal to:

$$\chi^2_{3N}(\epsilon)=\frac{\beta m(\beta m\epsilon)^{\frac{3N}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{\beta m\epsilon}{2}}}{2^{\frac{3N}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{3N}{2})}$$

Where $\epsilon$ is the squared sum of the Maxwell-Boltzmann distributed velocities. To convert it to a kinetic energy you have to scale once again by $\frac{m}{2}$, s.t. $E = \frac{m\epsilon}{2}$:

$$\chi^2_{3N}(E)=\frac{\beta (\beta E)^{\frac{3N}{2}-1}e^{-\beta E}}{\Gamma(\frac{3N}{2})}$$

Which is the distribution you were looking for.

P.S. For both of these rescalings I have used the general identity for $y=sx$: $p(y)=sp(sx)$ which is just a change of variables. I have also used some algebra to derive the above so they might not be immediately obvious but they should be readily demonstrable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Godzilla! So... are you saying the $p(\Gamma)$ you have mentioned upstairs can be simplified to the $\chi ^2$ distribution?

Comment: @megamence $p(\Gamma)$ is in this case the $3N$-dimensional normal distribution with variance $\frac{1}{\beta m}$. What you are interested in is the sum of the squares of the normal variables, which is the chi-square distribution instead. The derivation of the chi-square distribution isn't completely straightforward but if you are interested you can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_related_to_chi-squared_distribution#Derivation_of_the_pdf_for_one_degree_of_freedom

Comment: Note: I am only interested in the velocity space and I have implicitly integrated out the configurational contribution to the initial probability density, since it is just the $3N$-dimensional uniform distribution.